# .jar wont display

Tags: java, execute

Ok, so, for some reason, my .jar wont execute even though it does in eclipse. Heres my code, its not the best but, im experimenting. I need some help in getting it to execute outside of eclipse as the .jar file.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.Calendar;  // only need this one class
import javax.swing.*;
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// TextClock
public class CopyOftheclock {
//================================================================= main
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame clock = new TextClockWindow();
    clock.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    clock.setVisible(true);
}//end main
}//endclass TextClock


@SuppressWarnings("serial")
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// TextClockWindow
class TextClockWindow extends JFrame {
//=================================================== instance variables
private JTextField timeField;  // set by timer listener

//========================================================== constructor
public TextClockWindow() {
    // Build the GUI - only one panel
    timeField = new JTextField(7);
    timeField.setFont(new Font("sansserif", Font.PLAIN, 48));

    Container content = this.getContentPane();
    content.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    content.add(timeField); 

    this.setTitle("Norway");
    this.pack();

    // Create a 1-second timer and action listener for it.
    // Specify package because there are two Timer classes
    javax.swing.Timer t = new javax.swing.Timer(1000,
          new ActionListener() {
              public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                  String a = "";
                  Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
                  int h = now.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
                    if (h==24)
                    {
                        h=8;
                        a = "A.M";
                    }
                    if (h==1)
                    {
                        h=9;
                        a = "A.M";
                    }
                    if (h==2)
                    {
                        h=10;
                        a = "A.M";
                    }
                    if (h==3)
                    {
                        h=11;
                        a = "A.M";
                    }
                    if (h==4)
                    {
                        h=12;
                        a = "P.M";
                    }
                    if (h==5)
                    {
                        h=1;
                        a = "P.M";
                    }
                    if (h==6)
                    {
                        h=2;
                        a = "P.M";
                    }
                    if (h==7)
                    {
                        h=3;
                        a = "P.M";
                    }
                    if (h==8)
                    {
                        h=4;
                        a = "P.M";
                    }
                    if (h==9)
                    {
                        h=5;
                        a = "P.M";
                    }
                    if (h==10)
                    {
                        h=6;
                        a = "P.M";
                    }
                    if (h==11)
                    {
                        h=7;
                        a = "P.M";
                    }
                    if (h==12)
                    {
                        h=8;
                        a = "P.M";
                    }
                    if (h==13)
                    {
                        h=9;
                        a = "P.M";
                    }
                    if (h==14)
                    {
                        h=10;
                        a = "P.M";
                    }
                    if (h==15)
                    {
                        h=11;
                        a = "P.M";
                    }
                    if (h==16)
                    {
                        h=12;
                        a = "P.M";
                    }
                    if (h==17)
                    {
                        h=1;
                        a = "A.M";
                    }
                    if (h==18)
                    {
                        h=2;
                        a = "A.M";
                    }
                    if (h==19)
                    {
                        h=3;
                        a = "A.M";
                    }
                    if (h==20)
                    {
                        h=4;
                        a = "A.M";
                    }
                    if (h==21)
                    {
                        h=5;
                        a = "A.M";
                    }
                    if (h==22)
                    {
                        h=6;
                        a = "A.M";
                    }
                    if (h==23)
                    {
                        h=7;
                        a = "A.M";
                    }
                  int m = now.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
                  int s = now.get(Calendar.SECOND);
                  timeField.setText("" + h + ":" + m + ":" + s + " " + a);
              }

          });
    t.start();  // Start the timer
}//end constructor
}//endclass TextClock
```

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't execute? Does it compile? What is the error.

Comment: It seems to work for me. How are you compiling the file?

Comment: You need to describe how you're running it, and what the error is. That's quite an if statement you have there.

Comment: Hour 17 is 1A.M.? Really? And don't you think you could do the conversion more... Uhm... Programatically, instead of a huge series of if statements?

Comment: i am exporting it with eclipse, right click the class file, click export, and then jar. im sorry if im getting it wrong, im new at this :\.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Making the Jar

#### Export as a runnable jar

[image]
[image]

If you are successful in making a jar then follow the next step.

### Running it from console

#### Method 1

`java [-options] -jar jarfile [args...]`

**Note:** Where `[-options]` are the arguments for the JVM and `[args...]` is for your jar

Also this will only work if your jar manifest has an entry for main class like this:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path: .
Main-Class: CopyOftheclock
```

#### Method 2

set your class path like this:

```
set classpath=clock.jar;.;%classpath%
```

and after this:

```
java [-options] class [args...]
```

Where `class` is your class with main method. Also `class` should be fully qualified i.e. if it is in `package a.b.c` then the class should be `a.b.c.CopyOftheclock`. Also, you should be firing the java command from the topmost packages parent.

#### Method 3

I am not sure about *nix based OS but on windows just right click on the jar and select run with `java` or `javaw`. But for that the manifest file must have the `main class` entry, otherwise it would fail.

**Note:** See the `java -help` for more details on `[options]`

Comment: ohh, i know what happned, i dont have the option to do that :(

Comment: what options ?? please be more specific, that would help in solving your issue.